# How do I find what the date will be next Sunday 12 am from now and then add 10 hours to it

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I have this code

```
today = datetime.now().date() 
# prints: 2022/1/14
rd = REL.relativedelta(days=1, weekday=REL.SU)
nextSunday = today + rd
#prints : 2022/1/16
```

How do i add 10 hours to the date so i can get a variable nextSunday_10am that i can substract to the current time

```
difference = nextSunday_10am - today
```

and schedule what I need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same thing as suggested by @Dani3le_ more directly with the following:

```
def getSundayTime(tme: datetime.date) -> datetime:
    nxt_sndy = tme + timedelta(days= 6 - tme.weekday())
    return datetime.combine(nxt_sndy, datetime.strptime('10:00', '%H:%M').time())
```

This will compute calculate the next Sunday and set time to 10:00

Answer (score 1):

You can add hours to a DateTime by using `datetime.timedelta()`.

```
nextSunday += datetime.timedelta(hours=10)
```

For example:

```
import datetime


today = datetime.datetime.today()
print("Today is "+str(today))
while today.weekday()+1 != 6: #0 = "Monday", 1 = "Tuesday"...
    today += datetime.timedelta(1)

nextSunday = today + datetime.timedelta(hours=10)
print("Next sunday +10hrs will be "+str(nextSunday))
```

Comment: This is decent code but this is leading me to my original problem of not finding the date on sunday 10 am, it just adds 10 hours relative to my own time

Comment: Oh, I may had misread your question. Still, hope I gave you a useful answer.

Comment: Yup, its still valid code, not exactly what i was looking for but someone could definetly need it at one point